# Trying to do an != option but failing

Tags: python, python-3.x

im tying to make an option to open a text file and the input can be with a .txt and the end and without. So far with the code i provided it works when i don't include a '.txt' but when i do it adds a '.txt' causing an error

```
if choice == 'r':
           fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
           if fileName!= fileName.endswith('.txt'):
               fileName= fileName + '.txt'
               readEmployees(fileName)
```

readEmployees is used later to read the file and display names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be sure without the desired output, but did you mean to write,

```
if choice == 'r':
           fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
           if not fileName.endswith('.txt'):
               fileName= fileName + '.txt'
               readEmployees(fileName)
```

Basically, `.endswith()` returns a boolean, so you are comparing `filename` to a boolean.

Comment: You could also instead use `fileName += '.txt'` to be a bit more efficient.

Comment: @duckboycool: As it happens, in CPython, both versions are equally efficient on runtime (and on other versions of Python, likely equally inefficient); the optimization for extending a string in-place (violating the technical immutability rules) works for both. In terms of avoiding repeating yourself, yes, `+= '.txt'` is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

The `endswith()` method returns true or false. So, your if statement should just contain the `endswith()` method, and not compare it to the filename. Also, I'm guessing you want to call `readEmployees(filename)` regardless of if it ends with .txt. So, you should put it outside of your if statement because your current code only calls it if the file does not end with .txt.

```
if choice == 'r':
    fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
    if not fileName.endswith('.txt'):
       fileName = fileName + '.txt'
    readEmployees(fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have pointed out, the issue was with comparing a string to a boolean value:

```py
>>> fileName = "file.txt"
>>> fileName
'file.txt'
>>> fileName.endswith(".txt")
True
```

---

Just a side-note: here's a more concise, although perhaps less easy on the eyes way of writing your code using a ternary operator:

```py
if choice == "r":
    fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
    fileName += ".txt" if not fileName.endswith(".txt") else ""
    readEmployees(fileName)
```

Read up about [ternary operators here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python)